# how do we import external scripts in Vue-cli

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm trying to use a ready template that uses revolution slider in my vue-cli app, how can i use the external script of this template?

I've tried to import the scripts that the template used in the  tag in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Balad | Govt HTML Template</title>
<!-- CSS Files -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/color.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/slick.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="icon" href="images/fav.png" type="image/png">
<!--Rev Slider Start-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/rev-slider/css/settings.css"  type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/rev-slider/css/layers.css"  type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/rev-slider/css/navigation.css"  type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--Rev Slider End-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>
        <strong>We're sorry but brikma-website doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to
          continue.</strong>
      </noscript>
      <div id="app"></div>
      <!-- built files will be auto injected -->

<!-- JS --> 
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script> 
<script src="js/slick.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/custom.js"></script> 
<!--Rev Slider Start--> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rev-slider/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rev-slider/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rev-slider.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rev-slider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rev-slider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.carousel.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rev-slider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rev-slider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rev-slider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.migration.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rev-slider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rev-slider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rev-slider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rev-slider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and i past the body of the template in the vue js component that renderd by #app

the jquery work on the site, but there are other problems, the revolution slider Not displayed,

I also tried to use this packages with node modules but i have seen the work is hard with this way

and here is my project structure : 
this folders in the public i put them there that index.html can reach them directly, this folders were in the template (all js and css ...)

[image]

I don't have any problems in console and with the build

Comment: can you please share your folder structure?

Comment: Can you confirm that the rev-slider JS scripts are indeed being loaded on the page? Also, since VueJS renders the page asynchronously, it might be too late for rev-slider to initialize/instantiate a slider whose template is found in your VueJS component. You will probably have to manually initialize/instantiate it on the `mounted` hook.